# When are Browsers or W3C going to change Pages to Space?

Tags: 3d, spaces

Ok I have a question? Why are web Browsers still thinking in 2d not 3d... Meaning Why can't we scroll left or up in the negative? Well, not actually scroll but at-least send the user to any negative space. I understand the browser has to have a horizontal and vertical starting point of 0... But why don't they think out side of the box and allow web designers/developers the ability to send the user into the negative.  Basically sending the user any where on a page (and the word "page" should be changed to "space").  Breaking the space into four quadrants. Top Left, Top Right, Left, and Right (Right is where we will start. It's the normal starting position.  The space we currently use).. This would allow for creative web page design.

Comment: It's the year 2010!  Where are the flying cars!

Comment: What you're proposing still sounds 2D to me...

Comment: I know it sounds 2d but it gives preparation for the 3d web space...

Answer (score 1):

You can do some 3D stuff in web browser that supports canvas.

Here are some exemple :

http://www.benjoffe.com/code/demos/canvascape/

http://gyu.que.jp/jscloth/

Comment: I might not have articulated myself correctly... So i will give an example.  Lets say I Have a web page that has 9 menu links.  The first one anchors the page to the negative left. The second one to the negative top, and so on.  So that the user is sent to different parts of the page using positive and negative coordinates.. Does that make sense..?